# Codeception fails to find Kernel.php in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing, codeception, symfony4

I'm trying to use `Codeception` to make some functional acceptance tests on project using `Symfony 4`. Project environment is built with docker containers(just simple pgsql container and php container that run `php bin/comnsole serve` and expose 8000 to different local port).
I've met the problem that running tests specified with symfony extension causes an error:

```
bin/codecept run -v
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.4.0
Powered by PHPUnit 7.0.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

In Symfony.php line 300:

  [Codeception\Exception\ModuleRequireException]
  [Symfony] module requirements not met --

  Kernel class was not found in /srv/dsp-blacklister/src/Kernel.php. Specify directory where file with Kernel class for your application is located with `app_path` parameter.
```

But Kernel is situated there:

```
/srv/dsp-blacklister/src # ls -la
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root           224 Feb 28 09:35 .
drwxr-xr-x   26 root     root           832 Feb 28 16:18 ..
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            96 Feb 28 08:16 Controller
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root           160 Feb 28 10:39 Entity
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2010 Feb 28 09:35 Kernel.php
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root           128 Feb 28 11:39 Migrations
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            96 Feb 28 09:09 Repository
```

Answer (score 3):

Your kernel is in a different namespace. There isn't a fix for this yet, other than the temporary hack below (add to the bottom of your kernel class)

```
class_alias(Kernel::class, 'App\Kernel', true);
```

Comment: The problem is on the Symfony.php file on codeception, It tries to load appKernek or app/Kernel.
I fixed with the solution shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use the `kernel_class` parameter to specify the kernel namespace:

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Functional
        - Symfony:
            kernel_class: AppTest\Kernel
```

Comment: LOL i've made this fix PR to Codeception 6 month ago and than they get other PR for 14 days ago. I like this open source team))

Answer (score 0):

For Codeception v5.0.5 adding to all suits:

```yaml
modules:
    enabled:
        - Symfony:
            app_path: 'src'
            environment: 'test'
```

worked for me.